# What observable phenomena show that we live in the pre-Messianic era?

Tags: theology, science, olam-haba-world-to-come

There's no doubt that we live in a very special era of fast and huge technological, social, scientific, economic, psychological and other changes. The world is also getting closer to the 6000 year bar, which traditionally marks the coming of the Moshiach.

What observable phenomena correlate to our Sages' outlook on the pre-Messianic era?

Comment: Maybe this a dumb question, but isn't every day that the Mashiach hasn't come considered the "pre-Messianic era?" Even 1,000 years ago? When did this "era" begin? You may want to add that definition into your question.

Comment: Per Rabbi Uri Sherki's understanding of Rabbi Kook: rampant secularism amongst the Nation of Israel and throughout the world.

Comment: If the sages said there'san era or pre-Moshiach, so I just follow their idea, I didn't make it up.

Comment: I'm sure you will find this shiur heplful https://youtu.be/3Usb6U6AqFY

Answer (score 6):

[Sanhedrin 98a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.98a.3?lang=bi)

> ואמר רבי אבא אין לך קץ מגולה מזה שנאמר (יחזקאל לו, ח) ואתם הרי ישראל ענפכם תתנו ופריכם תשאו לעמי ישראל וגו'‏
>
> **And Rabbi Abba says: You have no** more **explicit** manifestation of the **end** of days **than this** following phenomenon, **as it is stated: “But you, mountains of Israel, you shall give your branches, and yield your fruit to My people of Israel**, for they will soon be coming” (Ezekiel 36:8). When produce will grow in abundance in Eretz Yisrael, it is an indication that the Messiah will be coming soon.
>
> *(**Translation** and elucidation courtesy of sefaria.org)*

Comment: Great thank you, +2! As the verse continues "כִּ֥י קֵרְב֖וּ לָבֽוֹא" many interpret it as the Prophet's reference to the return of Ezrah time, not our time specifically. It's interesting what era R'Aba talks about? He made Alyah to Eretz Israel and it seems that he was impressed by its agricultural development under the Roman Empire and thought Moshiach could come any time soon?

Comment: Can you please, help me to decipher the following statement of the same Gemmorah "*When there are no wages for work and no rent paid for use of one’s animal, that is an indication that the coming of the Messiah is at hand"*

Comment: @AlBerko Remember that you are quoting Navi. So what the "mountains of Israel" means needs to be understood. Also, are the fruits referring to the return of the 'gluska'ote' (the miraculous fruit like the spies brought back), which were not present with Ezra, or to some other type of fruit?

Comment: @YaacovDeane I don't see the Navi mentioning גלוסקאות?

Comment: Judging by its surrounding context (36:26-27), especially when compared to parallel ideas expressed in Jeremiah (31:33), I'm not sure literal fruits (of trees) were the prophet(s)'s *primary* concern.

Answer (score 1):

Sefer [Yosef Chochma](https://shops.hidabroot.org/product/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3-%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94---%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3-%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%99) (2011) quotes from the Mishna and the Gemarah (Sotah 49b & Sanhedrin 97b) there are 20 signs from Chazal about the time before Moshiach:

1) Insolence will be greater

2) There will be a great inflation

3) Even though grapes are in abundance, the wine will be expensive

4) Leadership and government officials will be far removed from Tora and 
will not lead the nation in the way of the Tora

5) The generation will not accept rebuke

6) When people get together, the conversation will frequently center on women, immorality, and infidelity

7) The Galil will be destroyed and the Gavlan (Golan) will be desolate

8) The people that live in the border will be expelled and moving from city to city because no one will have compassion on them

9) The wisdom of our Rabbis will be ridiculed

10)Those who fear sin will be dispised

11) The truth will be missing, no one knows who will hold the truth and everything will be in a state of confusion and doubt

12) The young will embarrass the Elderly

13) The Elderly will stand before the young

14) Sons will curse their fathers

15) Daughters will rebel against their mothers

16) Brides will turn against their mother-in-laws

17) One’s own family members will be his enemies

18) The face of the generation will be that of a dog. That means that people won’t realize when a tragedy occurs to them, it’s from Heaven, to convey a message. Mida keneged mida. Because when you hit a dog with a stick, the dog will think the stick is beating him. He doesn’t realize that, and the will continue attacking the stick.

19) A son will no be ashamed before his father and all shame and courtesy will disappear from the world

20) At that time, our only hope will be in Our Merciful Father in Heaven. We will have to solely trust in HaShem that he will redeem us and bring Moshiach Tzidkenu, Amen!

Comment: The sefer was written by Rav Yosef Mizrachi with the endorsement of Rav Shelomo Mosheh Amar, Chief Rabbi of Yerushalayim and several other prominent Rabbis

Comment: I agree with the math "complaints", but, as I've often stated, here, "As my age increases, my math abilities decrease", and "As I get older, my math decisions don't count any more." Offhand - I've personally seen manifestations of # 9 - # 17. But, I question if #17 is a problem if your family members are intentionally not Torah-observant and badger you when you are. I thin it would be permissible to make them your enemies, no?

Comment: @alberko except for #7, they’ve all been fulfilled

Comment: Did brides and mothers-in-law ever have a good relationship?

Comment: 20th is not a point. I'm familiar with the Gemmoros, but they all are too vague to judge. Like the first חוצפא ישגא - what do you compare our generation to?

Comment: Not really sure how you don’t see it as a point. How are they vague? They’re pretty specific

Comment: @AlBerko do you see the 20th point now? as clear as can be